# Application Settings replace connection string from referenced DLL

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a class library where I store a connection string in the application settings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="FAB.IMon.DataAccess.Properties.Settings.IMonConnectionString"
      connectionString="X" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

I implemented a WCF Soap service wich references this library. In my WCF service I want to use connection string Y. So I changed the web.config:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="FAB.IMon.DataAccess.Properties.Settings.IMonConnectionString"
      connectionString="Y" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

When I start the Webservice the service uses X instead of Y, why?

Comment: ur updating ur config file in debug folder?

Comment: change the connection string in library project from x to y.

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  Class libraries do not use their own configuration file - they use the configuration file of the application that is referencing them.  Can you show the code you use to get the connection string from the config file?